# File Reading in java to obtain a single line by providing line number

Tags: java, arrays, file

I have a java file reader method. The file consist of many line ( upt 100 lines). I was interested to read and store Line 2 and as well as line 5 - 15 while am storing them into an arrayList.
The issue am having is, I dunno how to get the content of a specific line
For example : this is the file content.

```
Time after time
Heart to heart
Boys will be boys
Hand in hand
Get ready; get set; go
Hour to hour
Sorry, not sorry
Over and over
Home sweet home
Smile, smile, smile at your mind as often as possible.
Alone, alone at last
Now you see me; now you don’t
Rain, rain go away
All for one and one for all
It is what it is
```

Java API that am using is

```
 File f = new File ("t.txt");
```

and

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f))
```

Comment: The *simplest* approach would be to use `Files.readAllLines()` to read the whole file into memory as a list. Not terribly efficient, but for only 100 lines it's probably not worth writing anything more efficient.

Comment: so, that means i will have to read the content twice and do the necessary operation i need to take @JonSkeet

Comment: Why would you need to read the content twice? You read it once, and you have a list of all the lines. You can then do what you like with those lines, without having to touch the file again.

Comment: yeah, I figure it out a way to read it by using List<String> ls = Files.readAllLines(f.toPath()).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java 7 introduced [NIO.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html)<sup>1</sup> which includes class `java.nio.Files` which declares method [readAllLines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-)<sup>2</sup>. Since you state that your file may contain a maximum of 100 lines, method `readAllLines` seems appropriate. Then all you need to do is indicate the index[es] of the line[s] you want. The below code demonstrates.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

public class FileLine {
    public static void showLines(List<String> lines, int first, int last) {
        if (lines != null  &&  first >= 0  &&  last < lines.size()  &&  first <= last) {
            for (int i = first; i <= last; i++) {
                System.out.println(lines.get(i));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path path = Paths.get("t.txt");
        try {
            List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path); // throws java.io.IOException
            showLines(lines, 2, 2);
            System.out.println("================================================================");
            showLines(lines, 5, 14);
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the index of the first line in the `List` is 0 (zero).

The output when I run the above code is:

```
Boys will be boys
================================================================
Hour to hour
Sorry, not sorry
Over and over
Home sweet home
Smile, smile, smile at your mind as often as possible.
Alone, alone at last
Now you see me; now you don’t
Rain, rain go away
All for one and one for all
It is what it is
```

Alternatively, if you want to collect certain file lines into a separate list, then consider the following code (which is slightly changed from the above code).

```java
public class FileLine {

    public static List<String> getLines(List<String> lines, int first, int last) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        if (lines != null  &&  first >= 0  &&  last < lines.size()  &&  first <= last) {
            for (int i = first; i <= last; i++) {
                list.add(lines.get(i));
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path path = Paths.get("t.txt");
        try {
            List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path);
            List<String> selectedLines = getLines(lines, 2, 2);
            selectedLines.addAll(getLines(lines, 5, 14));
            System.out.println(selectedLines);
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Running the alternative code gives the following output:

```
[Boys will be boys, Hour to hour, Sorry, not sorry, Over and over, Home sweet home, Smile, smile, smile at your mind as often as possible., Alone, alone at last, Now you see me; now you don’t, Rain, rain go away, All for one and one for all, It is what it is]
```

<sup>1</sup> NIO was introduced in Java 1.4
<sup>2</sup> To be precise, that method was added in Java 8. In Java 7 you also had to indicate the *charset* of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Files are read through *streams* and each line is accessed sequentially, not randomly. One way to handle this is to have a counter that you check inside a loop, something like:

```
int count = 1;     // line counter
String line;       // current line being read

while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if(count == 2 ||
      (count >= 5 && count <= 15))
      arrayList.add(line);
    count++;
}
```

Comment: having a counter was something I thought, but i was looking if there was an alternative option. 
Thanks @david mordigal

Answer (score 0):

Extract the logic you need into a method looking at the general case.

Given a file `f`, read only a subset of lines. One way of looking at this is with a method like

```
List<String> readLines(File f, Function<Integer, Boolean> check);
```

You could define such a method as follows:

```
List<String> readLines(File f, Function<Integer, Boolean> check) throws IOException {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int count = 0;
    String line;
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f))) {
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            count++;
            if (check.apply(count)) {
                list.add(line);
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Defining the check function as appropriate whereby given an integer it will return true / false if the line is to be added, you can generalize for different use cases.

For exmaple (in your case), the check function would be

```
Function<Integer, Boolean> check = lineNumber -> lineNumber == 2 || (lineNumber >= 5 && lineNumber <= 15);
```

Answer (score 0):

*get line(s) by their respective line-number with lambda*

```
Set<Integer> linesToGet = Set.of(2, 5, 15);
try(Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("test.txt"))) {
  int[] line = {1};
  List<String> list = stream.filter(s -> linesToGet.contains(line[0]++))
      .collect(toList());
}
catch (IOException ex) {…}
```

gets: `[Heart to heart, Get ready; get set; go, It is what it is]`